# Simulate a dead lock on SQL server using single client and single session

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to simulate a deliberate deadlock on sql server, where I could test a piece of code which would do retries. Need a query/SP/Func which I can execute, later this query fails with 1205/deadlock and trigger my retry logic.

constraints:
-Within a single client n single session. (Kind of reading a meta data n locking itself in a single session, may be)

Tried with success:
-mocking custom SQL exception n successful recovery.
-multithreaded approaches.

Now, need a SQL component which does this in a single session.

Edit: reframed the question for better suggestions.

Comment: Deadlock in the DB happens when sessions are trying to get objects locked by another sessions. So, session1 locks table1 and waits for session2 to unlock table1. Meanwhile, session2 is waiting for session1 to unlock table1. This is when a deadlock occurs. You can't simulate it without establishing at least 2 sessions

Comment: _Not looking for this coz it's not auto testable in my suits._ Why not? Threads and tasks have been a thing for a while now.

Comment: Rethinking a little... if you need two clients/connections to test this it sounds like you have dependencies on concrete classes like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc.. If you're using `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` properly you should be able to throw an `SqlException` with `.Number = 1205` from a mock.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning tried it! gives out all kind of errors: MARS, Parallel conn/trans not allowed when I make other thread sleep, etc. So "My" test suit, let say I'm maintaining it, can provide only this much flexibility.  Coming to throwing new custom Sql exception with 1205 number: I need the actual integration with DB. Mock and unit test for my reties have already figured out. Thanks for being exact, appreciate  it!

Comment: If all you're testing is resilience if a command fails, you can simulate failure server-side through `THROW`/`RAISERROR`. Replicating a deadlock for that is rather pointless (whether with one or multiple sessions) because, if you can do exactly that on a real setup, what you normally want to do instead is fix the deadlock (so it's a regression test, not an integration test), whereas if you're using a purely theoretical setup to make it replicable, it's no better than just testing an error that's always produced.

Comment: @JeroenMostert throwing a new custom Sql Exception with 1205 id, I've already figured it out. Its easier that way. Now: I need straight from the Horse's Mouth; in my test I want to deliberate a deadlock and recover out of it, by that I'll not make a assumption of nature of the exception/id/all its content and more over in reality I got into an exception and successfully recovered, I need that in my tests.  Thanks.

Comment: @ekochergin - you **can** simulate it from a single connection

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree about the connection, but the OP says "single session"

Comment: @ekochergin - it is possible in a single session. The code in my answer only creates a single session. The deadlock graph has a single session id deadlocking itself. The internal transaction creating the TVP runs as a nested transaction in the same session as the outer transaction. In SQL Server "sessions" and "connections" are largely the same thing except when using MARS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently possible.

The following code deadlocks itself

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TYPE dbo.OptionIDs AS TABLE( OptionID INT PRIMARY KEY )
EXEC ('DECLARE @OptionIDs dbo.OptionIDs;')
ROLLBACK
```

This is a long standing issue due to the use of internal system transactions when creating the instance of the TVP that can't access the lock taken by the user transaction.

At some point it may be fixed though

Comment: I had tried the same with Go in bw, it was failing (coz Go is a non T-SQL, native to SSMS) later also tried without it, but no luck. EXEC ('DECLARE OptionIDs dbo.OptionIDs;') This line did the trick! Thank You @Martin

Comment: used this script here for test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062183/need-a-built-in-way-to-add-deadlock-resilience-to-dapper-for-existing-repos-with Thanks!