# Need a built in way to add Deadlock Resilience to Dapper for existing repos without altering them

Tags: c#, deadlock, dapper, data-access-layer, polly

Need to make all **the existing repos** (around 30+) fault tolerant to deadlock and recover from it with log and wait approach.

Tried with success: I've answered below a custom SqlResiliencyPolicy using Polly after some research and tailored it to the project.

But, what I seek: The present way (PFB answered), demands me to either

1. Wrap all the existing DB calls with `await _policy.ExecuteAsync`  OR
2. Provide custom overloads which accepts `IAsyncPolicy` param. and later call the intended method. Sort of extension to IDbConnection:

`public static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IDbConnection connection, object primaryKey, IAsyncPolicy policy) =>` `return await _policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => GetAsync<T> (...));`

In both ways, I need to change all my 30+ repos. But, is there a built-in way in dapper/some-other-approaches, where we can

> "configure a Policy in startup and auto-magically all DB calls via
> dapper become resilient (fall backs to their fault tolerant mechanism)
> Similar to the ways of http clients resilience where policy is added
> while you register a client"

By this: will've code changes to minimum, need not touch repos but only the startup.

I've a below approach and sort of need an improvement over it.

Comment: You can create [extension methods on the IDbConnection] (https://davemateer.com/2021/08/29/dapper-and-polly) to add retry capability.

Comment: Yep, that's point 2^^ with a little code snippet there. But I'm in need of more magic where I don't need to DI/even add a parameter, do such unicorn (if I may) exists?

Comment: I'm unaware of any global error handler for Dapper where you might be able inject retry logic. In case of MSSQL it throws an SqlException on which you can react and that's all. I'm not a Dapper expert so I might say invalid statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will be by-far the apt approach to have minimal/no changes to the existing repo. Kudos to the blog written by @Sergey Akopov and to my colleague who pointed at this blog.

**Short answer**: Use a Decorator pattern to wrap the `SQL Client's Connection and Command instances` and Inject the retry policy from Polly to these decorators. By this, will be able to wrap all the SQL execution endpoints with retry policy. This will be compatible with Dapper, as it's an extension to `IDbConnection`.

Create a DI'able Retry policies which encapsulate the policy inside it. Also, We can totally decouple the Policy to separate class and register it for DI (not shown in this answer, but this is followed in other answers, don't forget to use `PolicyRegister` if you have more than one policy).

Git repo: https://github.com/VinZCodz/SqlTransientFaultHandling

**Details**:

Interface for Policy, no async methods since `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` endpoints are not async.

```
public interface IRetryPolicy
{
 void Execute(Action operation);
 TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> operation);
}
```

Concrete implementation, which embeds the policy inside and wraps retry logic for all the DB calls via Sql Client thus Dapper.

```
public class RetryPolicy : IRetryPolicy
{
    private readonly ILogger<RetryPolicy> _logger;
    private readonly Policy _retryPolicy;

    private readonly ISet<int> _transientDbErrors = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1205 });
    private const int _transientErrorRetries = 3;

    public RetryPolicy(ILogger<RetryPolicy> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _retryPolicy = Policy
                        .Handle<SqlException>(ex => _transientDbErrors.Contains(ex.Number))
                        .WaitAndRetry(
                        retryCount: _transientErrorRetries,
                        sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(attempt * 100),
                        onRetry: LogRetryAction);
    }

    public void Execute(Action operation) => _retryPolicy.Execute(operation.Invoke);

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> operation) => _retryPolicy.Execute(() => operation.Invoke());

    private void LogRetryAction(Exception exception, TimeSpan sleepTime, int reattemptCount, Context context) =>
        _logger.LogWarning(
            exception,
            $"Transient DB Failure while executing query, error number: {((SqlException)exception).Number}; reattempt number: {reattemptCount}");
}
```

Now, somehow we need to inject this policy to SqlClient's con and cmd, need a `sealed` class which `'is-a' DbConnection` (DAL endpoints will remain intact) and also `'has-a' DbConnection` (mimic the operations but with retries):

```
 public sealed class ReliableSqlDbConnection : DbConnection
 {
    private readonly SqlConnection _underlyingConnection;
    private readonly IRetryPolicy _retryPolicy;

    private bool _disposedValue;
    private string _connectionString;

    public ReliableSqlDbConnection(string connectionString, IRetryPolicy retryPolicy)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _retryPolicy = retryPolicy;
        _underlyingConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public override string ConnectionString
    {
        get => _connectionString;
        set => _underlyingConnection.ConnectionString = _connectionString = value;
    }
    public override void Open()
    {
        _retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
        {
            if (_underlyingConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _underlyingConnection.Open();
            }
        });
    }
    public override string Database => _underlyingConnection.Database;
    public override string DataSource => _underlyingConnection.DataSource;
    public override string ServerVersion => _underlyingConnection.ServerVersion;
    public override ConnectionState State => _underlyingConnection.State;
    public override void ChangeDatabase(string databaseName) => _underlyingConnection.ChangeDatabase(databaseName);
    public override void Close() => _underlyingConnection.Close();
    protected override DbTransaction BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) => _underlyingConnection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
    protected override DbCommand CreateDbCommand() => new ReliableSqlDbCommand(_underlyingConnection.CreateCommand(), _retryPolicy);
}
```

Since, we are instantiating SqlConnection whenever its asked for we also need to dispose it properly, following `derived type dispose pattern` as suggested by Microsoft:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_underlyingConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _underlyingConnection.Close();
            }
            _underlyingConnection.Dispose();
        }
        _disposedValue = true;
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Following similar approach to `DbCommand`:

```
public sealed class ReliableSqlDbCommand : DbCommand
{
    private readonly SqlCommand _underlyingSqlCommand;
    private readonly IRetryPolicy _retryPolicy;

    private bool _disposedValue;

    public ReliableSqlDbCommand(SqlCommand command, IRetryPolicy retryPolicy)
    {
        _underlyingSqlCommand = command;
        _retryPolicy = retryPolicy;
    }

    public override string CommandText
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.CommandText;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.CommandText = value;
    }

    public override int CommandTimeout
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.CommandTimeout;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = value;
    }

    public override CommandType CommandType
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.CommandType;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.CommandType = value;
    }

    public override bool DesignTimeVisible
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.DesignTimeVisible;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.DesignTimeVisible = value;
    }

    public override UpdateRowSource UpdatedRowSource
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.UpdatedRowSource;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.UpdatedRowSource = value;
    }

    protected override DbConnection DbConnection
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.Connection;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.Connection = (SqlConnection)value;
    }

    protected override DbParameterCollection DbParameterCollection => _underlyingSqlCommand.Parameters;

    protected override DbTransaction DbTransaction
    {
        get => _underlyingSqlCommand.Transaction;
        set => _underlyingSqlCommand.Transaction = (SqlTransaction)value;
    }

    public override void Cancel() => _underlyingSqlCommand.Cancel();

    public override int ExecuteNonQuery() => _retryPolicy.Execute(() => _underlyingSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());

    public override object ExecuteScalar() => _retryPolicy.Execute(() => _underlyingSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());

    public override void Prepare() => _retryPolicy.Execute(() => _underlyingSqlCommand.Prepare());

    protected override DbParameter CreateDbParameter() => _underlyingSqlCommand.CreateParameter();

    protected override DbDataReader ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) => _retryPolicy.Execute(() => _underlyingSqlCommand.ExecuteReader(behavior));

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _underlyingSqlCommand.Dispose();
            }
            _disposedValue = true;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Existing DAL side:

DI:

```
services.AddScoped<IRetryPolicy, RetryPolicy>();
services.Configure<DbConnectionOption>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
});
```

Lazy load the Decorator:

```
_connection = new Lazy<IDbConnection>(() =>
{
    return new ReliableSqlDbConnection(_dbOptions.ConnectionString, _retryPolicy);
});
```

Xunit Test: This test actually creates a deadlock on single session and reties it.

Thanks to @Martin Smith for awesome script, more on script: [Simulate a dead lock on SQL server using single client and single session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019632/simulate-a-dead-lock-on-sql-server-using-single-client-and-single-session)

```
[Fact]
public void It_creates_reliablesqldbConnection_and_deadlock_itself_to_log_and_retry()
{
    var logger = new FakeLogger<RetryPolicy>(); //create your own logger.
    using var reliableSqlDbConnection = new ReliableSqlDbConnection(_fixture.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DataContext"],
                                                                    new RetryPolicy(logger)); //create your own fixture.

    //Awesome script which deadlocks itself on single con and process with it's meta data.                                                              
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<SqlException>(() => reliableSqlDbConnection.ExecuteAsync(
                                            @"BEGIN TRAN
                                            CREATE TYPE dbo.OptionIDs AS TABLE( OptionID INT PRIMARY KEY )
                                            EXEC ('DECLARE @OptionIDs dbo.OptionIDs;')
                                            ROLLBACK "));
                                            
    Assert.Equal(LogLevel.Warning, logger.Logs.Select(g => g.Key).First());

    var retries = logger.Logs[LogLevel.Warning].First();

    Assert.Equal(3, retries.Count());
    Assert.Equal("Transient DB Failure while executing query, error number: 1205; reattempt number: 1", retries.First());
}
```

**Summary:**
With this, `Open` Connection, `ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteNonQuery` etc will have retry capabilities wrapped around them, which will ultimately be invoked by all Dapper endpoints.

By this, will've code changes to minimum, need not touch repos but only the startup.  Just by providing a wrapper/decorator to SqlClient's connection and command will be able to inject and retry with custom policies.

Comment: The github link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Have implemented 2nd approach ^^: This decouples policies to be DI'ed to the existing repos. Extension methods to `IDbConnection` takes care of wrapping policy around existing methods.

```
public class SqlResiliencePolicyFactory
{
    private readonly ISet<int> _transientDbErrors = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1205 });
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public SqlResiliencePolicyFactory(ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IPolicyRegistry<string> GetSqlResiliencePolicies(int transientErrorRetries = 3)
    {
        return new PolicyRegistry
        {
            { 
                "DbDeadLockResilience", 
                Policy
                    .Handle<SqlException>(ex => _transientDbErrors.Contains(ex.Number))
                    .WaitAndRetry(
                        retryCount: transientErrorRetries,
                        sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(attempt * 100),
                        onRetry: LogRetryAction)
            },
            { 
                "DbDeadLockResilienceAsync", 
                Policy
                    .Handle<SqlException>(ex => _transientDbErrors.Contains(ex.Number))
                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                        retryCount: transientErrorRetries,
                        sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(attempt * 100),
                        onRetry: LogRetryAction)
            }
        };
    }
    
    private void LogRetryAction(Exception exception, TimeSpan sleepTime, int reattemptCount, Context context) =>
        _logger.Log(
            LogLevel.Warning,
            exception,
            @$"Transient DB Failure while executing query,
                error number: {((SqlException)exception).Number};
                reattempt number: {reattemptCount}");
}
```

In startup:

```
DapperExtensions.SetPolicies(new SqlResiliencePolicyFactory(_logger, _configuration)
                            .GetSqlResiliencePolicies());
```

Create extension methods in a separate class to wrap the policy around existing methods of your repo.
Extension methods:

```
public static class DapperExtensions
{
    private static Policy _policy = Policy.NoOp();
    private static IAsyncPolicy _asyncPolicy = Policy.NoOpAsync();

    public static void SetPolicies(IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> readOnlyPolicyRegistry)
        {
            _policy = readOnlyPolicyRegistry.Get<Policy>("DbDeadLockResilience");
            _asyncPolicy = readOnlyPolicyRegistry.Get<IAsyncPolicy>("DbDeadLockResilienceAsync");
        }

    public static T GetFirstWithRetry<T>(this IDbConnection connection,
                                        string? sql = null, object? parameters = null, IDbTransaction? transaction = null) where T : class =>
        _policy.Execute(() => connection.GetFirst<T>(sql, parameters, transaction));

    public static T QueryFirstOrDefaultWithRetry<T>(this IDbConnection connection, string sql,
                                          object? parameters = null, IDbTransaction? transaction = null) =>
        _policy.Execute(() => connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<T>(sql, parameters, transaction));

    public static async Task<bool> UpdateAsyncWithRetry<T>(this IDbConnection connection, T entityToUpdate, IEnumerable<string> columnsToUpdate,
                                                      IDbTransaction? transaction = null) where T : class =>
        await _asyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await connection.UpdateAsync(entityToUpdate, columnsToUpdate, transaction));

    //Similarly, add overloads to all the other methods in existing repo.
}
```

Now,

1. The existing repo's are independent of policy (no DI to repo).
2. Policies are kept at separate place following SRP.
3. Dapper extension can change policies for easy testing.

Thus, existing repos have to change the name and call the above wrapper instead of calling the dapper methods itself, policy will be applied. Don't forget to regression test the repo's once.

Comment: It seems okayish. I might change the `SetPolicies` method to anticipate a `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry` instance and retrieve the desired policies by itself.

Comment: I don't understand why retrieve methods are synchronous whereas the update is async. My best guess is that they are just samples.

Comment: Yea, these are just to demonstrate how we wrap policies around your existing dapper quires, not actual methods though. I'm yet to break ground on better approach, so WIP. BTW thanks for the edit and corrections.

Comment: @PeterCsala changed the SetPolicies, make sense.

Comment: I tried this approach.  The trouble is that `DapperExtensions.SetPolicies` must be called in `Configure` and not `ConfigureServices` since you need to pass a logger into it, meaning that any services trying to use the Dapper extension methods to access the DB before that call happens (I have a few) fall over because the policies haven't yet been set.

Answer (score 0):

My approach after following some research:

```
public class SqlResiliencyPolicy 
{ 
    private readonly ISet<int> transientDbErrors = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1205 });
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public SqlResiliencyPolicy(ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IAsyncPolicy GetSqlResiliencyPolicy(int transientErrorRetries = 3)
    {
        return Policy
            .Handle<SqlException>(ex => transientDbErrors.Contains(ex.Number))
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                retryCount: transientErrorRetries,
                sleepDurationProvider: attempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(attempt * 100),
                (exception, sleepTime, reattempt, context) =>
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, exception, $"Transient DB Failure while executing query, error number: {((SqlException)exception).Number}; reattempt number: {reattempt}");
                });
    }
}
```

In startup:

```
 services.AddScoped(_ => new SqlResiliencyPolicy(_logger, _configuration).GetSqlResiliencyPolicy());
```

Ctor DI: In Existing Repos DI to Ctor with a private IAsyncPolicy backing field:

```
private readonly IAsyncPolicy _policy;
```

Last step: Wrap all the dapper calls with

```
await _policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {<existing DB call>});
```

Comment: I have a minor suggestion. It might make sense to use [`PolicyRegister`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry) to register policies into your DI.

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks! have implemented it using PolicyRegister along with point 2 approach [will be sharing the code shortly].

Comment: Why do you `AddScoped` and not `AddTransient` here?